# Timeline disappears after I add my first task (Project Summary WP)

Tags: sharepoint-online, project-summary-web-part

I'm trying to do this programmatically, but I don't get the behavior I expect even when using the GUI, so let's start from there:
In SP Online I create a team site. I select to create a "Project Summary" Control and associated Task list. I all looks fine and dandy

[image: Before first task is added]

But as soon as I add my first task I only get a heads-up on the first task in the task list. The nice looking time line is gone!

[image: After first task is added to tasklist]

In some rare cases I have seen the timeline showing only the first task (but not the others) in the high lighted part (lower image). What am I doing wrong? I can't find another way to add tasks except for the "Edit the task list"-link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in your task list > check the task and click on add to timeline as shown below:

[image]

Go back to your home page it will be shown in Project Summary web part.

[image]

Comment: You are welcome bro  @Cowborg ,

Comment: Done  (15 chars more)